# Calculate average and remove from list in Scala

Tags: scala, average

I am on my first week with Scala and struggling with the way the code is written in this language.

I am trying to write a function that determines the average number in a list and removes the values below that average. For example:

I have this list:

```
List[(String, Int)] = List(("A", 1), ("B", 1), ("C", 3), ("D", 2), ("E", 4))
```

The result should be `2.2`.

So the function should also remove the entries `("A", 1)`, `("B", 1)` and `("D", 2)` because they are below the average.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the average of the second elements of the list of tuples, you don't need to do the sum yourself because Scala has a builtin function for that. First we need to transform the list of tuples to a list of `Int` values, we can do that using the `map` function as shown below

```
val average = list.map(_._2).sum/list.size.toDouble
```

Now you have the average, you can filter your list based on its value

```
val newList = list.filter(_._2  < average)
```

Note that we didn't remove anything from the list, we created a new one with filtered elements

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
val sum = list.map(_._2).sum
val avg: Double = sum / list.size.toDouble

val filtered = list.filter(_._2 > avg)
```

Note this is traversing the list twice, once for summing and once for filtering. Another thing to note is that Scala `List[T]` is immutable. When you filter, you're creating a new `List` object with the filtered data.

Answer (score 1):

```
val average = list.map(_._2).sum / list.size.toDouble
list.filter(p => p._2 >= average)
```

You need to cast to `Double`, else average would be cast to an `Int` and be imprecise. The `filter` only keeps the element greater than the average.